# how to add data HTML table in column wise in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The table is called school. it has two columns called `students` and `teachers`. I want to add teachers and students names to respective column. this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="school.xsl"?>
<school>
    <students>
        <student>
            <name>Lakshman</name>
        </student>
        <student>
            <name>Tharindu</name>
        </student>
    </students>
    <teachers>
        <teacher>
            <name>Sarath</name>
        </teacher>
        <teacher>
            <name>Hemantha</name>
        </teacher>
        <teacher>
            <name>Upali</name>
        </teacher>
    </teachers>
</school>
```

this is my xsl file as referenced by xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>School</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Students</th>
                        <th>Teachers</th>
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                       <xsl:for-each select="school/students/student">
                           <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td></tr>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="school/teachers/teacher">
                            <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td></tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it prints the table like this.

[image]

is there anyway to add students and teachers names to their respective column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="students" select="school/students/student"/>
    <xsl:variable name="teachers" select="school/teachers/teacher"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>School</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Students</th>
                        <th>Teachers</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$students"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="stud-count" select="count($students)"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$teachers[position() > $stud-count]"/>
                </table>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="student">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$teachers[$pos]/name"/></td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="teacher">
     <tr>
       <td>&#160;</td>
       <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: great it worked. thank you. but before it worked you have to add last two template tags inside stylesheet tag. you are adding them outside of the stylesheet tag

Comment: that would be great, if you can provide an explanation about your answer.

Comment: @lakshman, sorry about the misplaced end tag. As for how it works, the code stores the `teacher` elements in a global variable to have access to it elsewhere in the stylesheet, the processes all `student` elements that exist to create a `tr` table row, populated with the `name` of each student and the `name` of each teacher in the same position (e.g. `name` of first student and `name` of first teacher`). In case there are more teachers than student the code processes those teachers as well, mapping each to a `tr` row populated with an empty cell in the first column and the name in the second.